# Plot time of two different for loops

Tags: matlab

I have two loops:

```
for x = 1:100
    tic
    for n=1:x
       #some code
       t(n) = toc
    end

    plot(t)

end

for y = 1:100
    tic
    for n=1:y
       #some code
       t(n) = toc
    end

plot(t)

end
```

If I just run one of the for loops and plot the time, it works perfectly. But I if I run both loops and I hold on from first to second series of plotting, I get lots of lines in the graph.

All I want is two graphs representing the two times of the functions plotted.

Comment: What is the purpose of the inner loop (`for n=1:y` or `for n=1:x`)?

Comment: In my code, I just create random matrices of 1 to 100. Then I go through each matrix (1x1, 2x2, etc. and do some code)

Comment: Do you mean to get values of t for 1+2+...+100 individual cases? Or are you calculating one value of t for each value of x (or y)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would do it:

```
t1 = zeros(100*100);
i = 1;
for x = 1:100
    tic
    for n=1:x
       #some code
       t1(i) = toc
       i = i + 1;
    end
end


t2 = zeros(100*100);
i = 1;
for y = 1:100
    tic
    for n=1:y
       #some code
       t2(i) = toc
       i = i + 1;
    end
end

figure();
plot(t1);
hold on;
plot(t2)
```

Comment: `hold all` is better than `hold on` as it doesn't upset the `colororder`